# A linear algebra question relating to showing how every element $X\in SO(3)$ is a rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

If $X\in SO(3)$, I can see how $X$ has an eigenvalue of $1$ and there is thus a normalizable eigenvector $u$ as the axis or rotation (an invariant subspace).

Then one can claim there are orthonormal vectors $v$ and $w$ (with right-hand orientation) that are a basis of the plane in the orthogonal compliment of $u$.

Next there is an orthogonal matrix $A=[\;u\quad v\quad w\;]$.

At last here is my linear algebra question: Given

> > $A^{-1}XA=A^{T}XA=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&Y\end{bmatrix}$

where $Y$ is a matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

I would appreciate help as to how to show the conjugation by $A^{-1}$ gives the form of the matrix on the RHS. (I do know $A^{-1}=A^{T}$.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule: in order to see what a matrix looks like, it suffices to see it does to the standard basis vectors $e_1,e_2,e_3$.  In particular: if $e_1 = (1,0,0), e_2 = (0,1,0), e_3 = (0,0,1)$, then for $i = 1,2,3$, the product $Me_i$ gives the $i$th column of the matrix $M$.

Note that
$$
[A^{-1}XA]e_1 = A^{-1}X[Ae_1] = A^{-1}X u = A^{-1} u = e_1
$$
So, the first column of the matrix is $e_1$ (as we expected).  On the other hand, the matrix $A^TXA$ should itself be orthogonal, since it satisfies $[A^TXA]^T[A^TXA] = I$.  With that, the first row of $A^TXA$ should have length $1$.  So, the second and third entries of the first row must be zero.

All together, we have figured out what the first row and column of $A^TXA$ are, as desired.